# Aggregating votes from different users with some constraints and probabilities

Tags: probability, optimization

Suppose we have $N$ users that can vote for a given question by "Yes" or "No". Each user have a probability which is considered as the confidence that we have in that user (e.g. a user may have a probability of 0.8 to answer the question correctly, and a probability of 0.2 to answer it wrongly). Each user requesst an amount of money as a reward for answering the question. I (as the asker of the question) have a limited budget for paying the users.

Given this budget, which users should I ask to maximize the final answer to be correct (i.e. the answer obtained after aggregating the asked answers)?

**Additional informations:**

"what does it mean for a vote to be correct": if the question is "does 10/2 equals 5?" then "Yes" is a correct answer to this question; now if the probability associated to the user is 1, that means that the user will answer this question correctly because it have a very good knowledge of the domain of the question (mathematics); if the probability associated to the user is 0, this means that the user will answer this question wrongly; if the probability associated to the user is 0.5, then his answer may be correct ("Yes 10/2=5") with a probability of 0.5, or maybe wrong wt probability 1-0.5.

What I want is to maximize the fact of getting the good final answer by aggregating the obtained answers (want to know that the answer to my question is "Yes" 10/2=5). For this, which users should I ask (given my budget, and given that each user request a given amount of money to accept to answer my question), and how to aggregate their answers in order to have the correct one.

What is called "vote" is the classical aggregation of the answers, by taking the most common answer among the received ones (if there is more "Yes" answers then ok I will consider the final result as "Yes), but in my real example I have some constraints: probabilities associated to users, ammount of money requested by each user to answer my question, and the total amount of money that I have, so I need to also consider these constraints. If you want, forget about the word "vote" in the question, just tell me who to ask and how to aggregate the answers that I get.

Comment: Several interpretations of the objective are possible. For instance, do you want to maximize the *expected* number of correct answers? Or perhaps you want to maximize the chance that every answer is correct?  Or the chance that the number of correct answers equals or exceeds a minimum threshold? Also, what role does "voting" have in this question? And what does it mean for a vote to be "correct"? What is the distinction between a "vote" for and an "answer" to a question? It is hard to see how your question can reliably or objectively be answered until you clarify these issues.

Comment: @whuber "what does it mean for a vote to be correct": if the question is "does 10/2 equals 5?" then "Yes" is a correct answer to this question; now if the probability associated to the user is 1, that means that the user will answer this question correctly because it have a very good knowledge of the domain of the question (mathematics); if the probability associated to the user is 0, this means that the user will answer this question wrongly; if the probability associated to the user is 0.5, then his answer may be correct ("Yes 10/2=5") with a probability of 0.5, or maybe wrong wt proba 1-0.5

Comment: @whuber What I want is to maximize the fact of getting the good final answer by aggregating the obtained answers (want to know that the answer to my question is "Yes" 10/2=5). For this, which users should I ask (given my budget, and given that each user request a given amount of money to accept to answer my question), and how to aggregate their answers in order to have the correct one.

Comment: @whuber What is called "vote" is the classical aggregation of the answers, by taking the most common answer among the received ones (if there is more "Yes" answers then ok I will consider the final result as "Yes), but in my real example I have some constraints: probabilities associated to users, ammount of money requested by each user to answer my question, and the total amount of money that I have, so I need to also consider these constraints. If you want, forget about the word "vote" in the question, just tell me who to ask and how to aggregate the answers that I get. Is it clear ?

Comment: Much better, thank you.  It would be good for you to incorporate these explanations within the question itself so that hasty readers (who might otherwise neglect to review the comments) will not misunderstand.  Incidentally, I would attach *high* value to a user who has a probability of $0.2$ of answering the question correctly: by reversing their answer, they become just as reliable as the person with a probability of $0.8$!

Comment: @whuber Yes reversing the answer of users having a low probability may be a good suggestion when we consider this probability to be a "probability of answering the question correctly", thank you. I can also consider the probability to be about the "reliability" of the user according to his domain knowledge about the question, in this case users with a low probability (having nearly no knowledge about the domain) may answer randomly, in this case it is better to consider their "probability of answering the question correctly" to be 0.5.

Comment: It is important to have an operational, quantitative interpretation of "reliability." If it cannot be translated into a probability, then you cannot compute the distribution of correct answers, so you cannot even get started with solving this problem.  This begs the question of how you determine the "reliability" of voters in the first place: that is likely estimated from previous experience or simply guessed. Thus the probabilities are themselves uncertain and perhaps ought to be modeled (in a Bayesian fashion) by prior probabilities.

Comment: @whuber You are right, how you determine the "reliability" of voters is another somehow complicated problem which depend on many indices like behaviour of voters... For the current question I'll just assume that the probabilities that we are talking about are indeed "probabilities of answering the question correctly".

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the "expected number of correct answers" for each user--for example, your hypothetical user with probability 0.8 of answering correctly has an expected number of correct answers equal to 0.8, when you give him a single question.

Then, divide by your cost for each user. Suppose your user with probability 0.8 asks for \$2 dollars. When you divide, you get an "expected number of correct answers per dollar" of 0.4 for that user. A user with probability 0.6 of answering correctly but who asked for only \$1 would have an "expected number of correct answers per dollar" of 0.6.

Now you have a few possible approaches. The simplest is to use a greedy algorithm, and go through an select as many users as you can within your budget starting with the highest "expected number of correct answers per dollar." This is an approximate algorithm.

A better approach is to treat this as a variant of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Solving it is NP-hard, but there are polynomial time approximations which are better than the greedy algorithm above.

Comment: (Note that I'm talking just about one question to ask to users). If for example I have a very big budget (say infinit) which is sufficient to ask all the users, then if I ask all the users, the final answer that I aggregate/deduce may be worse (have less chance to be correct) than the case where I just ask only the first user which have an ENCAD equals to 0.98 (very hight) ... Your approximate algorithm is not considering such cases.

Comment: The answer you deduce will only be worse after asking all the users if you do a naive analysis of the answers you get, in which case it's best to just ask the one best user you can afford. Since you have information on how reliable each user is, you can do an analysis using that information such that every additional answer you get from a user, no matter how unreliable that user is, will help you estimate a better overall answer.

Comment: Of course, at some point it's just not worth asking more users, but that's a separate question.

Comment: This is also a part of my question, and of your approximate algorithm: Using the information on how reliable each user is, how can you check that every additional answer you get from a user, will help you estimate a better overall answer ?

Comment: From an information-theoretic perspective, the user is a noisy channel. The "truth" is input at one end, and the user outputs their answer which is equal to the truth with probability $p$ and not equal to the truth with probability $1-p$. The only case in which the user transmits no information at all is if $p = 0.5$ exactly. Unless you already have perfect information (i.e., you have a user who answers correctly with probability one), then the information received from the user will help you answer the question, assuming that different users are independent.

Comment: +1 This can be reframed as a [bounded knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems) or, if the voters vary from question to question, as a multiple-constraint knapsack problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Christensen But you didn't really answered the last question: How can you decide to stop asking users? i.e., how can you check that the current better overall answer can probably not be improved by asking a new user ? I mean algorithmically speaking you have a sorted vector where each entry i is the ENCAD of the i'th user; you start with the first answer (of the 1st user having the highest ENCAD), you still have budget, you ask the 2nd user and get its answer, now you aggregate the 2 answers that you have, how can you check if you should or not ask another user ? What do you compute?

Comment: @whuber the difference with the knapsack problem is that in our case, we need to maximize a sort of expected correctness for the overall answer (after aggregating all the received answers), while for the knapsack problem we do our best to put items in the sack until we can no more add items to it. There is no relation between items, they should not be aggregated to give a final "good item", while in our case the answers are aggregated to get the best final answer.

Comment: This is now quite different from your original question! In your original question, presumably, you stop asking users when you run out of money. You can consider the new problem as a Bayesian updating problem if you're willing to write down a prior probability for each answer: at time zero, you have some probability of each answer being true (0.5 each, if you want). Then you start asking users. After each user, you check whether your current belief state satisfies some condition, which might be a hard line (e.g. I'm 90% sure of one answer) or, more realistically, would depend on costs etc.

Comment: I disagree, shn: this problem can be framed so that it is *precisely* a knapsack problem. The apparent differences you point to are not fundamental. Here, the "items" are not the voters, but rather increments along an efficient frontier and the costs are incremental costs to move along that frontier.

Comment: @shn, in your original question you specifically say that you wanted to figure out how to "maximize the amount of correct answers," which makes it very much like the knapsack problem. I'm getting the feeling now, though, that you actually want to do something quite different--you want to gain as much information about which answer is correct as possible. For example, for your original request a user with probability 0.001 of giving the correct answer is terrible, but if you're just trying to gain information, that user is just as good as one with probability 0.999 of giving the correct answer!

Comment: @Jonathan Christensen maybe I didn't asked the question well at the beginning. If I still have budget but asking more users will make the final answer worse, I indeed will prefer not to asking them. The Bayesian updating approach seems interesting here, I'm really not familiar with Bayesian statistics however. I, in fact, want to gain as much information about which answer is correct as possible. I did not understood what you want to say in the example of user with proba=0.001 and another with proba=0.999

Comment: @whuber in the knapsack problem we try to put the maximum number of items in the bag. In my case it is possible that with 3 users we get a better final answer than with 8 users ...

Comment: This is a mild generalization (and therefore even harder): you attempt to maximize the total *value* of the increments, rather than their count.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen can you update the answer to explain more precisely how to consider this problem as a Bayesian updating problem ?

Comment: @whuber so it can not be resolved using the usual knapsack problem solutions, right ?